# Does AUTOSAR contains out of the box components

Tags: autosar, automotive

I'm new to Autosar and trying to understand the concept theoretically.

I understand the philosophy, the goal, and the uses, but one thing that I don't completely understand is whether Autosar contains some out-of-the-box software components for developers? And if yes how can I recognize them in a binary file?

Comment: Whats about Autodrivingß>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the question uses the term “software-component” according to the meaning in AUTOSAR as some piece of application-level software:

no, there are no software-components standardized by AUTOSAR. There are PortInterfaces that are standardized and out of those PortInterfaces software-components could be created.

And also, some specifications postulate the existence of specific software-components, but this represents actually the opposite of a standardization. Those software-components are mostly postulated because it is not possible to standardize the respective functionality within the respective basic-software module (OEM/suppliers have proprietary approaches that they want to keep).

Answer (score 0):

AUTOSAR defines an architecture with certain methodology and exchange formats. The BSW below and including the RTE is also specified. The BSW modules/components and their interfaces are standardized and include the MCAL, HW Abstraction and Service Layer components.

From your question it's a bit unclear what you mean with

> some out-of-the-box software components for developers